# AWS Cognito is sending SMS messages without my permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, sms, amazon-cognito

I noticed a strange charge for SMS messages being sent a few months back and since our code doesn't yet support sending SMS messages, I have been investigating it.

It turns out AWS Cognito is sending text messages when we call "UpdateUserPool" to +12064350128 (206-435-0128).  This is not a phone number associated with our account, in our code, or with any of our personnel.  What's worse is that this AWS account hosts only development environments where the public doesn't have access.  So we know it's either an Amazon employee's number or a security leak (or both).

Has anybody else had this happen?  A google for that phone number turned up nothing, other than it is probably from somebody in Seattle.

Does anybody know what kind of data is being sent in these messages or how to figure out what's in them?  Is it passwords & confidential info?

I turned on SMS logging and this is all of the data I could gather:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "975e37a9-a5f1-5397-b6d0-63fdbad40d83",
        "timestamp": "2018-10-31 21:21:41.756"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+12064350128",
        "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone",
        "dwellTimeMs": 168,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 2514670
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I received the following from AWS support.  Looks like it's innocuous.  Whew!

> I completely understand your concern of AWS Cognito sending messages
>   to phone number +12064350128. I got in touch with the Cognito team and
>   found that it is an expected behaviour that when you make an
>   UpdateUserPool  API call,  a message is sent out to  +12064350128 and
>   this applies to all AWS accounts. The phone number +12064350128 is an
>   internal number and a message to this number is sent out to verify if
>   Cognito and SNS are integrated correctly so that Cognito can send SMS
>   to other numbers. Please note that no security information including
>   passwords is being passed in the content of this SMS message, It's
>   just a sample message indicating SNS is integrated with Cognito
>   correctly.
>
> Please be rest assured that we treat customer's data with utmost
>   privacy and we have a strict security mechanism in place to check any
>   fraudulent activities.
>
> I also completely agree that the above behavior needs to be documented
>   and hence I will be reaching out to the Cognito team to get this
>   updated in our docs to avoid further confusion.

Comment: If this is an internally generated SMS, why does it have a cost associated with it? i.e. why  am I being billed for an internal Cognito systems check?  Seems very suspect to me...

Comment: Yeah. Super suspect. They gave me a refund when I asked for it, but I guess I have to ask for it every month? Also, it took them weeks to figure it out and it was something like $0.81.

Comment: Thanks - I had been looking to use SMS to verify phone numbers but the AWS offering is just too flaky to be usable.  I ended up going with Twilio instead so have just put the max SMS send budget to $0 in SNS so none of the AWS SMS messages are transmitted.

Comment: Oh. That's smart.