# Cognito Forgot Password - Sending to Unknown Phone Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, forgot-password

I am using Cognito for auth.

I am currently using it for InitiateAuthCommand, ConfirmSignUpCommand, and RespondToAuthChallengeCommand **successfully with no issues.**

There is only user in my user pool. The phone ends in 0415.

[image]

But when I send ForgotPassword command to the same pool I get a success but to a different phone number.

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  CodeDeliveryDetails: {
    AttributeName: 'phone_number',
    DeliveryMedium: 'SMS',
    Destination: '+*******5547'
  }
}
```

I can't find anything online, but is this 5547 like a default number?

Checked cloudtrail logs for Cognito, see the request, but the destination phone number is fully masked.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: I have seen this if you try the Forgotten Password flow and enter an invalid phone number eg. 4455667788 in the hosted UI ... notice no leading "+" then you get the same symptom, the UI responds saying that it sent an SMS to some random number (different every time).  But we see no evidence in CloudWatch logs to show any outbound SMS.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173397/aws-cognito-is-sending-sms-messages-without-my-permission